# PostgreSQL with c# Backend sent unrecognized response type: o

Tags: c#, postgresql

I'm trying to execute the following function like ExecuteNonQuery in C#:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Fifty(cpfDe bigint,cpfPara bigint, valorDe decimal,valorPara decimal, idPagamento bigint)
RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE comissionamento bigint;
BEGIN
IF (cpfPara <> 0)
THEN
insert into tb_comissionamentos 
(
    cpf_autonomo, id_imobiliaria, cpf_comprador, 
    id_venda, id_pagamento, valor,
    id_status, data_alteracao, id_usuario, 
    valor_percentual_banco, valor_ted, valor_deb_boleto_comprador,
    valor_liquido, status_envio_efetivacao
) 
select 
    cpfPara, id_imobiliaria, cpf_comprador, 
    id_venda, id_pagamento, valorPara, 
    id_status, data_alteracao, id_usuario, 
    (valorPara * 0.02), valor_ted, 0.08, valor_liquido, 
    status_envio_efetivacao 
FROM tb_comissionamentos 
where 
    id_pagamento = idPagamento 
    and cpf_autonomo = cpfDe
    and valor = valorDe;

SELECT id_comissionamento 
    into comissionamento
FROM tb_comissionamentos
WHERE id_pagamento = idPagamento
AND cpf_autonomo = cpfPara; 

update tb_hist_comissionamentos set 
    cpf_autonomo = cpfPara,
    valor =valorPara,      
    valor_percentual_banco = valorPara * 0.02, 
    valor_deb_boleto_comprador = 0.08, 
    id_comissionamento = comissionamento
where 
    id_pagamento = idPagamento 
    and cpf_autonomo = cpfDe 
    and id_comissionamento = comissionamento;

delete from tb_comissionamentos 
where 
    id_pagamento = idPagamento 
    and cpf_autonomo = cpfDe 
    and id_comissionamento = comissionamento;
ELSE
DELETE FROM tb_hist_teds_enviadas
where id_comissionamento in 
    (SELECT id_comissionamento FROM
    tb_comissionamento where 
    id_pagamento = idPagamento 
    and cpf_autonomo = cpfDe     
    and valor = valorDe);

DELETE FROM tb_teds_enviadas
where id_comissionamento in 
    (SELECT id_comissionamento FROM
    tb_comissionamento where 
    id_pagamento = idPagamento 
    and cpf_autonomo = cpfDe     
    and valor = valorDe);

DELETE FROM tb_hist_comissionamentos
where 
    id_pagamento = idPagamento 
    and cpf_autonomo = cpfDe  
    and valor = valorDe;  

delete from tb_comissionamentos 
where 
    id_pagamento = idPagamento 
    and cpf_autonomo = cpfDe     
    and valor = valorDe;
END IF;
IF (cpfDe <> 0)
THEN
insert into tb_comissionamentos 
(
    cpf_autonomo, id_imobiliaria, cpf_comprador, 
    id_venda, id_pagamento, valor,
    id_status, data_alteracao, id_usuario, 
    valor_percentual_banco, valor_ted, valor_deb_boleto_comprador,
    valor_liquido, status_envio_efetivacao
) 
select 
    cpfPara, id_imobiliaria, cpf_comprador, 
    id_venda, id_pagamento, valorPara, 
    id_status, data_alteracao, id_usuario, 
    (valorPara * 0.02), valor_ted, 0.08, valor_liquido, 
    status_envio_efetivacao 
FROM tb_comissionamentos 
where 
    id_pagamento = idPagamento;

SELECT id_comissionamento 
    into comissionamento
FROM tb_comissionamentos
WHERE id_pagamento = idPagamento
AND cpf_autonomo = cpfPara; 

INSERT INTO tb_hist_comissionamentos( 
    cpf_autonomo,
    valor,      
    valor_percentual_banco, 
    valor_deb_boleto_comprador, 
    id_comissionamento,
    id_pagamento)
    VALUES(cpfPara, valorPara,valorPara * 0.02, 0.08, comissionamento,idPagamento);
END IF;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When i put all parameters in c# and call the execute non query i got the following message error:
Backend sent unrecognized response type: o

I can run the function normally in the Postgres console it works perfectly fine.
I think is the return type, but i don't know what should return to get an execution success.
EDITED
C# Code:

```
using (NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand())
                {
                    if (!dllConexao.open(Processadora.Comum.tipoConexao, 1, true))
                    {
                        clsRetorno.ret = 99;
                        clsRetorno.msg = "Sistema temporariamente indisponível, tente novamente mais tarde";
                    }
                    if (this.dllConexao.transactionIsOpen())
                    {
                        command.Transaction = this.dllConexao.TransacaoBd;
                    }
                    command.Connection = this.dllConexao.ConexaoBd;
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.CommandText = "Fifty";
                    var parm = command.CreateParameter();
                    parm.ParameterName = "cpfDe";
                    parm.DbType = DbType.Int64;
                    parm.Value = cpfDe;
                    var parm1 = command.CreateParameter();
                    parm1.ParameterName = "cpfPara";
                    parm1.DbType = DbType.Int64;
                    parm1.Value = cpfPara;

                    var parm2 = command.CreateParameter();
                    parm2.ParameterName = "valorDe";
                    parm2.DbType = DbType.Decimal;
                    parm2.Value = valorDe;

                    var parm3 = command.CreateParameter();
                    parm3.ParameterName = "valorPara";
                    parm3.DbType = DbType.Decimal;
                    parm3.Value = valorPara;

                    var parm4 = command.CreateParameter();
                    parm4.ParameterName = "idPagamento";
                    parm4.DbType = DbType.Int32;
                    parm4.Value = idPagamento;


                    command.Parameters.Add(parm);
                    command.Parameters.Add(parm1);
                    command.Parameters.Add(parm2);
                    command.Parameters.Add(parm3);
                    command.Parameters.Add(parm4);


                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    this.dllConexao.commitTransacao();
                    this.dllConexao.closeTransaction();

                }
```

Comment: What about showing the code in C# that calls this?

Comment: Sorry @Steve, i was sure that i pasted the code, anyway edited!

Comment: Uhm, not sure if it makes any difference, but the last parameter is an Int32 while the function expects a bigint

Comment: @Steve, actually this change the error to:
Backend sent unrecognized response type: _

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres has a rather blurred line between functions and stored procedures, in my opinion.  What you are doing seems like it would work in Oracle, and it might work fine in Postgres for all I know.

That said, the way you "execute" a stored procedure in PostgreSQL is to simply `select` the function.  In that spirit, this is a version of your code (with some refactoring -- please forgive me if you hate it) that I am pretty confident will execute:

```
using (NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(
    "select Fifty(:CDE, :CPARA, :VDE, :VPARA, :IDP)", this.dllConexao.ConexaoBd))
{
    if (!dllConexao.open(Processadora.Comum.tipoConexao, 1, true))
    {
        clsRetorno.ret = 99;
        clsRetorno.msg = "Sistema temporariamente indisponível, " +
           "tente novamente mais tarde";
    }
    if (this.dllConexao.transactionIsOpen())
    {
        command.Transaction = this.dllConexao.TransacaoBd;
    }

    command.Parameters.Add("CDE", NpgsqlDbType.Bigint);
    command.Parameters.Add("CPARA", NpgsqlDbType.Bigint);
    command.Parameters.Add("VDE", NpgsqlDbType.Numeric);
    command.Parameters.Add("VPARA", NpgsqlDbType.Numeric);
    command.Parameters.Add("IDP", NpgsqlDbType.Bigint);

    command.Parameters[0].Value = cpfDe;
    command.Parameters[1].Value = cpfPara;
    command.Parameters[2].Value = valorDe;
    command.Parameters[3].Value = valorPara;
    command.Parameters[4].Value = idPagamento;

    command.ExecuteScalar();

    this.dllConexao.commitTransacao();
    this.dllConexao.closeTransaction();
}
```

I changed the name of the parameters on purpose to not match the names of the parameters in the function.  This is because it doesn't matter.  So long as your SQL lists the names of the parameters with the `:` or `@` and that corresponds to your named `NpgSqlParameter` values, you will be good to go.

If your datatyping matches perfectly (long, long, decimal, decimal, long), you can even refactor this one step further:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("CDE", cpfDe);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("CPARA", cpfPara);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("VDE", valorDe);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("VPARA", valorPara);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("IDP", idPagamento);
```

The other great thing about this is if you do have an exception, I believe the error message will probably be pretty helpful.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what i need, a better error message and seeing it works! Awesome. Thanks.